# Raspberry Pi not opening web browser when using webbrowser.open(“”)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, chromium

I have recently aquired a RFID-RC255  for use with my Raspberry Pi, I want it so that when I scan a specific tag a web browser opens using VoiceMonkey to trigger an automation on my Alexa. Here is my Code:

```py
 import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 
 from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522

 import webbrowser


 reader = SimpleMFRC522()

 try:
         id, text = reader.read()
         print(id)
         print(str(text))
         url = 'https://docs.python.org/'
         webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

 finally:
         GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I run this code using python3 in console, it finishes with exit code 0 (as it should), though it does not open chromium nor any other browser on the pi. (I replaced the links with python). Is there something I am doing wrong, or not configured? I know that SPI is enabled on the Pi, but it does not seem to affect it.